# Google Search Console coverage lists 5xx errors for URLs that have never existed

Tags: google-search-console, error-reporting

I've a problem with Search Console.
For some months now the "Coverage" report has been detecting many "5xx" errors caused by URLs that don't exist and have never existed on my site.

[image]
[image]

What can it depend on?

Comment: Have you inspected the URLs to see where Google found them?

Comment: Have you looked at your server's error_log to determine why they have 500 errors rather than "404 Not Found"?

Comment: Have you checked if your site has been hacked?  Hackers often create lots of bogus URLs on your site.

Comment: Hi,from a more detailed verification, it seems that the errors are generated by requests from Google bot that moreover "invents" these URLs. Is there any way to avoid this problem? What does the strange behavior of the bot depend on?

Thanks Giusy P.

Comment: It is very unlikely that Googlebot is inventing URLs.  Googlebot always picks up URLs from somewhere else.  It's either going to be bad links on your own site, external links, JavaScript code that looks like links, or form values.  Have you used the inspect URL tool in search console to see what Google says about where it found the URLs?

Comment: If _you_ request one of these URLs in the browser what response do _you_ get?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller  Thanks for your assistance.
Upon inspection of the last strange URL detected (on May 26), if I am not mistaken, it turns out to be an unindexed URL found by Googlebot on desktop.
I would like to send a screnshot, as in the original question, but I have not found a way. I'm sorry but I'm new here.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite
if I request one of these URLs in the browser, it refers to the non-existent page of my site, "This page does not appear to exist.
It appears that the link you are trying to reach is not working. Can you try to research?"

Comment: You can use the [edit] link beneath your question and add details, including screenshots directly in your question.

Comment: Hi @Stephen Ostermiller, I added the screenshot in the original question. This is what results in GSC when inspecting the last odd URL. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to know where Googlebot finds these links to my site?
Not being in the sitemap and not building them the same Googlebot, I deduce that these URLs are external links in some site that I do not know.
With Screaming Frog I did not get any suspicious external links.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two issues:

First, those inexistent URL's are being indexed in the first place, that probably menas that you have reference to them somewhere in your HTML. You can use an SEO tool like ScreamingFrog to spot these broken links.

> The Index Coverage report shows the Google indexing status of all URLs that Google knows about in your property. [source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en)

Second, Your website is not handling correctly the 404 pages; Make sure that any inexistent URL is responding with a [404 status code](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/http-network-errors#http-status-codes) so Google effectively know this pages no longer exist.

What you need to do?

1. Make sure those pages are responding with a 404 status code.
2. Run an SEO audit tool on your site to find and remove broken links.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks.  1) is it possible that there is a "fake" sitemap that refers to the ownership of my site?
I have submitted the sitemap and I believe that Google should only refer to the URLs communicated with the sitemap in its scans.
From the coverage report it would seem that Google also refers to my site many URLs that I have never created, as if there were two sitemaps: mine and one that includes these URLs.
So someone communicated these bogus URLs to Google by linking them to my property?
2) the management of non-existent URLs is very complicated. They are a huge number.

Comment: 1. I think that's very unlikely.
2. You don't need to handle every non-existent URL individually, if you are using Wordpress for example, by default you'll get a 404 page if the URL you are trying to visit doesn't exist. It looks like your template is throwing a 500 error before rendering the 404 page. See [How to Fix the 500 Internal Server Error in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/)

Comment: 1) if it's very unlikely who generates these URLs then?
I have checked with Screaming Frog and it doesn't detect any problems with the links, neither internal nor external.

Comment: Is there any way to know where Googlebot finds these links to my site?
Not being in the sitemap and not building them the same Googlebot, I deduce that these URLs are external links in some site that I do not know.
With Screaming Frog I did not get any suspicious external links.

Comment: @giuseppinapacifico "I believe that Google should only refer to the URLs communicated with the sitemap in its scans." - That's not the case. An XML sitemap is simply a "suggestion" and allows search engines to discover hard to reach URLs. For many sites, a sitemap is non-essential. Search engines will naturally crawl any URLs that they discover, from anywhere.

Comment: You should focus your effort in making sure that those URL's are returning a 404 instead of an 50x. Google will eventually stop crawling them, because after all those are legit 404 pages.